# Max width rect with trimmed text

Tags: css, svg, trim

Im a begginer with SVG.

I have some problems with max-width and trimming text. What I want to do is this:

```
<g class="step-wrapper">
  <rect class="step"></rect>
  <text x="5" y="20" class="step-name">Candidate Field Req / job</text>
</g>
```

I want the rect width to be the same width as the text tag with a max-width of 250px trimming this text. I couldnt do it with CSS and I dont know how to set the rect width if I dont know the text width.

Comment: is the height supposed to be the same as the text height too?

Comment: No, the rect height is 50px and the text height depends on the font size,  now is 15px aprox.

Comment: I want to do this http://postimg.org/image/3oyeez4rv/ @RobertLongson